# How to display specific data in combobox coming from database in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
        private void stdName()
        {
            string MyConnection2 = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=anecdotal;";
            MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
            MySqlDataReader row;
            MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT  `ID`, `student_id`, `name` FROM student", MyConn2);
            try
            {
                MyConn2.Open();
                row = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
                while (row.Read())
                {               //Display student in combobox id_no student_id and student_name
                    std_detail.Items.Add(row.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    std_detail.Items.Add(row.GetValue(1).ToString());
                    std_detail.Items.Add(row.GetValue(2).ToString());

                }
                MyConn2.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

Here's my question;
1.)How can I ouput in as one row in my combobox i'm fetching the pk_id,student_id,student_name?
2.)Since in my code I was trying to output it one by one how can make it as one output coming from the database?

> Currently in my code it output as a column instead of in one row only
> I want an output like this (0,BL20201339,CRUZ JUANO) for each loop

Comment: Create a class with 3 properties.  Populate a collection of them from the database.  Override `ToString` to get the desired display.  Then add them to your combo box.

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of tutorials on how to accomplish this basic functionality. Use a search engine before you post a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like below please:-

```
while (row.Read())
                {               
                    std_detail.Items.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}",row.GetValue(0).ToString(),row.GetValue(1).ToString(),row.GetValue(2).ToString()));

                }
```

Comment: that was fast thank you for that you just missed "," your answer was right thank you!

Comment: Updated! thanks! happy to help! please upvote:-)